# How can I debug a .dylib loaded into a java app using Xcode 14.1

Tags: java, xcode, debugging, intellij-idea

Yes I did search for "similar questions" the old ones are many years old the new environment is very different.  Xcode 14, Java 20, intellij idea latest version.

I am using idea to build and run the java app.  the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is proper for running.

I build the .dylib with Xcode.  And leave it open to the source for the library.
I put a breakpoint in the library in a call I will make from java later ( using panama generated glue )

I put a break point in java after java loads the .dylib and before where I want to break in the .dylib.

Then in Xcode I attempt to "Attach to Process" to the java process now waiting at a break point in the java app. ( I have a break point in the library set ) I use the process ID, I know it is the right one ( I print it from the app ) as "kill (id)" will kill the right one.

I get this error trying to attach the debugger:

> attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process. Look in the console
> messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach
> failed. The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely
> have logged an informative message about why it was denied.) then

The java app is run using the java VM I am on an M2 apple silicon macbook with Vetura 13.2 os

I found the Consle app and looked at the logs - nothing sticks out.  I guess this is some sort of permissions or security issue.
I am stuck using the vm I am using.  A way to enable this debugging ?

More info:

lldb shows the same problem on the command line,
I want to debug a library loaded by the process. Not the executable itself.

Do I need to have a debug version of the VM executable ?
Do I need to change it's permissions or it's owner ?
There are no log entries with the word "debugserver" in them I can find.

Anyway - where do I go from here ?
Thanks.
PK